# Android sdkmanager not found

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, flutter-dependencies, android-sdk-manager

I want to use flutter but I am getting this while running flutter doctor[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcxsD.png)
I have cmdline tools install as seen in below picture
[android sdk tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R96sY.png)
But when I use command "flutter doctor --android-licenses"
It is showing sdkmanager not found:-[Sdkmanagernot found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7M73.png)
I have tried literally everything mentioned on internet to remove this error but nothing works

Comment: Have you already enable Android SDK Command-line Tools already?  https://codeinu.net/language/shell/c1486786-flutter-doctor-android-licenses-android-sdkmanager-not-found

Answer (score 0):

```
 // try to set

flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk>
```